# Как лучше останавливать скрипт?

Tags: php, база-данных

есть скрипт, который необходимо останавливать по клику кнопки отмены.

сейчас для этого я держу в базе запись "cancel 1/0" и во время работы скрипта в цикле дергаю эту запись и проверяю значение cancel.

при старте скрипта устанавливаю cancel 1.

юзер кликает кнопку, cancel меняется с 1 на 0.

если 0, то делаю return и скрипт останавливается.

целесообразен ли этот метод? или лучше присмотреться к каким ниубдь другим вариантам? например файлы-флаги.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90613/discussion-between-dasauser-and-madfan41k).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сделал файлы-флаги, в которых записан статус работы скрипта

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вариант вполне рабочий, но для каждого экземпляра запущенного скрипта будет нужна отдельная запись в базе. Вообще такая запись есть уже в самой ос -- это pid запущенного процесса. Зная pid, в процесс можно послать сигнал, который можно обработать и завершить работу.

Вот например такой скрипт

```
<?php

pcntl_async_signals(true); // без этого обработчик не заработает

echo getmypid(), "\n";

$term = false;

pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, function() use(&$term) {
    $term = true;
});

while (!$term) {
    echo date("H:i:s\n");
    sleep(5);
}
echo "Bye!\n";
```

Если его запустить `php main.php`, то он будет висеть в бесконечном цикле. Если вызвать `kill pid`, то сработает обработчик и процесс завершится.

В любом случае принцип такой: запущенный скрипт как-то идентифицируется, ему передаётся сообщение о необходимости завершить работу.